# Как восстановить bluetooth LE-соединение после выключения bluetooth на телефоне, имея адрес устройства

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

Сервис работает так: при подсоединении устройства, его адрес сохраняется в БД. `Gatt` остается в состоянии `connect` и ждет нового соединения. Если выключить Bluetooth на телефоне и снова включить, то соединение теряется, причем теряется только на Android 6.

Вот мой получатель сообщений:

```
protected class ConnectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        logger.v(TAG + "------------------------ConnectBroadcastReceiver : onReceive  " + intent.getAction());
        if ((intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED))) {
            logger.v(TAG + "------------------------ConnectBroadcastReceiver : onReceive  " + intent.getAction());
            logger.v(TAG + "PairingBroadcastReceiver : CONNECTED");
        } 
        if (intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                bleDeviceManager.setApplicationContext(BluetoothLeService.this);
                bleDeviceManager.connectAll(bluetoothAdapter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот его фильтр:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(connectBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

Такой метод `connectAll` не дает никакой ошибки, но соединение на Android 6 после выключения и включения блютуза не восстанавливается.

```
@Override
public void connectAll(final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter) {
    mainThreadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            connectedGatt.clear();
            devicesList.clear();
            deviceHandlerMap.clear();
            logger.d(TAG + "connectAll");
            List<Sensor> sensors = databaseRepository.getConnectedSensors();
            for (Sensor sensor : sensors) {
                BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(sensor.getAddress());
                connectedGatt.add(new BleConnectionCompat(applicationContext, logger).connectGatt(device, true, callback));
                logger.d(TAG + "connect " + device.getName() + " " + device.getAddress());
            }

        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Класс `BleConnectionCompat`:

```
public class BleConnectionCompat {

    private final Context context;
    private Logger logger;

    public BleConnectionCompat(Context context, Logger logger) {
        this.context = context;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public BluetoothGatt connectGatt(BluetoothDevice remoteDevice, boolean autoConnect, BluetoothGattCallback bluetoothGattCallback) {

        if (remoteDevice == null) {
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Issue that caused a race condition mentioned below was fixed in 7.0.0_r1
         * https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.0.0_r1/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java#649
         * compared to
         * https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.1_r72/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java#739
         * issue: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d35167adcaa40cb54df8e392379dfdfe98bcdba2%5E%21/#F0
         */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M || !autoConnect) {
            return connectGattCompat(bluetoothGattCallback, remoteDevice, autoConnect);
        }

        /**
         * Some implementations of Bluetooth Stack have a race condition where autoConnect flag
         * is not properly set before calling connectGatt. That's the reason for using reflection
         * to set the flag manually.
         */

        try {
            logger.v("Trying to connectGatt using reflection.");
            Object iBluetoothGatt = getIBluetoothGatt(getIBluetoothManager());

            if (iBluetoothGatt == null) {
                logger.w("Couldn't get iBluetoothGatt object");
                return connectGattCompat(bluetoothGattCallback, remoteDevice, true);
            }

            BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = createBluetoothGatt(iBluetoothGatt, remoteDevice);

            if (bluetoothGatt == null) {
                logger.w("Couldn't create BluetoothGatt object");
                return connectGattCompat(bluetoothGattCallback, remoteDevice, true);
            }

            boolean connectedSuccessfully = connectUsingReflection(bluetoothGatt, bluetoothGattCallback, true);

            if (!connectedSuccessfully) {
                logger.w("Connection using reflection failed, closing gatt");
                bluetoothGatt.close();
            }

            return bluetoothGatt;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException 
                | IllegalAccessException 
                | IllegalArgumentException 
                | InvocationTargetException
                | InstantiationException
                | NoSuchFieldException exception) {
            logger.w(exception + "Error during reflection");
            return connectGattCompat(bluetoothGattCallback, remoteDevice, true);
        }
    }

    private BluetoothGatt connectGattCompat(BluetoothGattCallback bluetoothGattCallback, BluetoothDevice device, boolean autoConnect) {
        logger.v("Connecting without reflection");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return device.connectGatt(context, autoConnect, bluetoothGattCallback, TRANSPORT_LE);
        } else {
            return device.connectGatt(context, autoConnect, bluetoothGattCallback);
        }
    }

    private boolean connectUsingReflection(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt, BluetoothGattCallback bluetoothGattCallback, boolean autoConnect)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        logger.v("Connecting using reflection");
        setAutoConnectValue(bluetoothGatt, autoConnect);
        Method connectMethod = bluetoothGatt.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("connect", Boolean.class, BluetoothGattCallback.class);
        connectMethod.setAccessible(true);
        return (Boolean) (connectMethod.invoke(bluetoothGatt, true, bluetoothGattCallback));
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private BluetoothGatt createBluetoothGatt(Object iBluetoothGatt, BluetoothDevice remoteDevice)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        Constructor bluetoothGattConstructor = BluetoothGatt.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
        bluetoothGattConstructor.setAccessible(true);
        logger.v("Found constructor with args count = " + bluetoothGattConstructor.getParameterTypes().length);

        if (bluetoothGattConstructor.getParameterTypes().length == 4) {
            return (BluetoothGatt) (bluetoothGattConstructor.newInstance(context, iBluetoothGatt, remoteDevice, TRANSPORT_LE));
        } else {
            return (BluetoothGatt) (bluetoothGattConstructor.newInstance(context, iBluetoothGatt, remoteDevice));
        }
    }

    private Object getIBluetoothGatt(Object iBluetoothManager)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

        if (iBluetoothManager == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Method getBluetoothGattMethod = getMethodFromClass(iBluetoothManager.getClass(), "getBluetoothGatt");
        return getBluetoothGattMethod.invoke(iBluetoothManager);
    }

    private Object getIBluetoothManager() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Method getBluetoothManagerMethod = getMethodFromClass(bluetoothAdapter.getClass(), "getBluetoothManager");
        return getBluetoothManagerMethod.invoke(bluetoothAdapter);
    }

    private Method getMethodFromClass(Class<?> cls, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return method;
    }

    private void setAutoConnectValue(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt, boolean autoConnect) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field autoConnectField = bluetoothGatt.getClass().getDeclaredField("mAutoConnect");
        autoConnectField.setAccessible(true);
        autoConnectField.setBoolean(bluetoothGatt, autoConnect);
    }
}
```

Был взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280402/every-connection-request-is-being-treated-as-direct-connect-request-android-bl), из ссылки в первом ответе.

Если вместо соединения через этот класс сделать просто так

```
connectedGatt.add(device.connectGatt(applicationContext, true, callback));
```

- ничего не меняется.

Зато вот такой метод `connectAll`:

```
public void connectAll(final BluetoothAdapter btAdapter) {
    final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    logger.d(TAG + "reconnectAll");
    mainThreadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (BluetoothGatt gatt : connectedGatt) {
                 gatt.connect();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Дает вот такую ошибку:

```
02-27 18:13:12.639 24192-24192/com.tel.btandroid.debug core::DevManager :: reconnectAll
02-27 18:13:12.643 24192-24192/com.tel.btandroid.debug E/BluetoothGatt: android.os.DeadObjectException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
    at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.unregisterClient(IBluetoothGatt.java:891)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.unregisterApp(BluetoothGatt.java:692)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.close(BluetoothGatt.java:631)
    at com.tel.android.core.sensors.bluetooth.BLEDeviceManagerImpl$8.run(BLEDeviceManagerImpl.java:404)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

`connectedGatt` - это массив, в который запоминаются все `gatt`, при появлении новых устройств. 
И эта ошибка только на Android 6. И на пятом и на седьмом работает без проблем. И соединение восстанавливается в обоих вариантах `connectAll()`. Что не так с шестеркой, как восстановить соединение?

Comment: Так вы пытаетесь инициировать связь с устройством с "сервера", т.е. из сервиса к клиенту? Обычно такое вряд ли пройдёт так как инициация связи обычно происходит с клиента, а для уведомлений или подсоединений с сервера для этого нет. Вам может лучше проставлять на устройствах авто-подсоединение в случае включения Bluetooth?

Comment: Должно работать так: устройство время от времени включается, передает данные и выключается снова. Находится устройство при сканировании, создается гатт, соединяется. Потом, когда устройство отключается, гатт снова коннектит и ждет, пока это устройство снова включится. Когда оно включается в callback приходит сообщение. И  так работает, но после отключения и включения bluetooth, сообщение о включении устройства не приходит.

Comment: Это решение почему-то тоже не работает : https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble/internal/util/BleConnectionCompat.java на android 6.0.1

Comment: Вроде разобралась, когда и что надо конектить, но осталась проблема, которая описана здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280402/every-connection-request-is-being-treated-as-direct-connect-request-android-bl  А именно только на android 6  я получаю при GetRemoteDevice(address) недоделанный девайс без имени и с кривым гатт. Этот гатт соединяется и даже показывает state=0. Но во всяком случае он не способен получить сообщение от устройства, когда то включается. И решение, которое там приведено, не работает.

Comment: Если для решения нужна дополнительная информация, пишите, я выложу.

Comment: Вы можете самостоятельно ответить на свой собственный вопрос внизу, @Helena2977